# How to add sections in a ListView (android)?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I read this tutorial to create a Navigation Drawer with a ListView.
Link:   http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

How can I divide my ListView into sections and add a title for each section? (Like facebook application). I read many examples and tutorials, but no one is very clear.
Must I do override the getView method of an Adapter? Or..
I hope someone knows how to answer clearly. Thanks!!

This is my code:

```
public class NoLeague extends Activity{

    private ListView listView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private String[] items = {"Lega_1","Lega_2", "Option", "Logout"};


    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().
            getDrawable(R.drawable.banner));

        getActionBar().setTitle("TITOLOdiPROVA");
        setContentView(R.layout.noleague_layout);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.item_layout, items));

    }
}
```

This is the item_layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

This is the layout of my Navigation Drawer:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/noleague_image" >
    </LinearLayout>

            <!-- The navigation drawer -->
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#575555"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:background="#111" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search for [Sectioned Listview](https://www.google.com/search?q=sectioned+listview&oq=sectioned+listview&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2869j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)! you'll find many examples,

You check out [Amazing Listview](https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)! and [Expandable Listview](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html)!

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty slick [Using multiple layouts in Listview](http://antew.com/?p=162). It's for those who want to build something of their own. the Amazing Listview and Expandable Listview are ready to be used